# If p is a prime divisor of the n-th Fermat number, and k is the multiplicative order of 2 mod p then $k|p-1$

Tags: number-theory, fermat-numbers, multiplicative-order

In the question [Multiplicative order with Fermat numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3806749/minimal-solution-of-2k-equiv-1-pmodp-where-p-is-a-prime-divisor-of-the-fer), it is established that if p is a prime divisor of the n-th Fermat number $F_n=2^{2^n}+1$ then the multiplicative order of 2 mod p is $k=2^{n+1}$. The exercise, which is from Gerstein's *Introduction to Mathematical Structures and Proofs*, goes on to ask for a demonstration that $k|p-1$.

We have $2^k\equiv 1 \pmod{p}$

$2^k = qp+1$ for some integer q

$2^{2^n}+1=tp$ for some integer t.

The text offers little about Fermat numbers except that they are pair-wise relatively prime and that some of them are composite.

For n=6, a prime factor is p=641 and k=128 and $128|(641-1)$, so the relation holds in this case.

Where to go from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\gcd(2, p) = 1$ and $p$ is a prime, [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) states

$$2^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{p} \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Given that $k = 2^{n+1}$ is the [multiplicative order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_order) of $2$ modulo $p$, it must divide any positive power where the result is congruent to $1$ modulo $p$, so this means

$$k \mid p - 1 \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

More generally for any coprime $a$ and $n$, [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) says that

$$a^{\varphi(n)} \equiv 1 \pmod{n} \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

where $\varphi(n)$ is [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function). Thus, the multiplicative order of $a$ modulo $n$ must divide $\varphi(n)$.

For primes $p$, since $\varphi(p) = p - 1$, then Euler' theorem coincides with Fermat's little theorem.